# Show that the rational cohomology ring $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ needs at least two generators

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, cohomology, rational-homotopy-theory

Let $M$ be a simply connected closed Riemannian manifold. How does one find a necessary condition going both ways that may be imposed on $M$ (perhaps on the curvature of $M$ and on torsion) which guarantees that the rational cohomology ring $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ needs at least two generators? That is, how does one force $M$ not to have rational cohomology that is the quotient of a polynomial ring?

Cross-posting on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857279/show-that-the-rational-cohomology-ring-hm-mathbbq-needs-at-least-two-ge

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about a necessary condition, but if your rational cohomology ring has at least two generators, then your manifold has infinitely many distinct closed geodesics. I don't know any conditions on curvature that can control the number of distinct closed geodesics however ...

Comment: Yes, thank you @Tobias Shin. It does not necessarily have to be a condition on the curvature of $M$. I just need a way to force $M$ not to have a polynomial cohomology ring $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$. (Possibly imposing a condition on the metric of $M$?)

Comment: Presumably you're assuming that $dim H^k(M;\mathbb{Q})= 1$ for all $k \equiv 0 (\mod q)$ for some $1< q| dim M$? Also, I think you want to say that $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ is not the *quotient* of a polynomial ring.

Comment: I don't think such results are known. Some examples of geometrically interesting manifolds with singly generated rational cohomology can be found in  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210231 but there are many other examples and it is unclear how curvature could be relevant.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek I see, thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Ian Agol Yes, that the sequence of Betti numbers $\{b_k(\Lambda M; \mathbb{F}_p)\}_{k\ge 0}$ is unbounded for some prime $p\ge 2$ where $\Lambda M$ is the free loop space of $M$, i.e. $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ is not isomorphic to a truncated polynomial ring.

Comment: Coincidentally, I believe this has an analogy in Hamiltonian dynamics, but I cannot quite recall what it is exactly.

Comment: There is an equivalent condition in terms of rational homotopy groups: $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ requires more than one generator iff $\pi_{\rm odd}(M)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is more than one-dimensional.

Comment: Is this equivalent to a condition on torsion, by tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ (or a divisible group)? @MarkGrant

Comment: Can you say more about the context? Presumably you know something about a particular manifold $M$, what sort of information do you have?

Comment: The only information known about the Riemannian manifold $M$ is that it is simply connected and closed (indeed, it is a very general case). @DylanThurston

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus: well, it is a condition on the non-torsion part of the homotopy groups of $M$, since tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ killls torsion; see rational homotopy theory. (Torsion here has little to do with torsion in the sense of differential geometry.)

Comment: In dimension at most 5, the only examples of simply-connected manifolds with polynomial cohomology ring are spheres and $\mathbb{CP}^2$ by the generalized Poincaré conjecture and Freedman's theorem.

Comment: I also found a paper addressing the issue of polynomial quotient cohomology ring: https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1801 This obstructs certain polynomial rings in certain dimensions.

Comment: Another paper on this topic (classifying biquotients with singly generated cohomology): https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210231

Comment: Hi @MarkGrant, would you be able to explain why $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ requires more than one generator iff $\dim\pi_{\text{odd}}(M)\otimes\mathbb{Q}>1$?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus: Note that a basis for rational homotopy corresponds to a set of algebra generators of the minimal model. Now the claim follows from Proposition 1 of the paper of Vigue-Poirrier and Sullivan: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214433729

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $M$ is simply-connected and has reducible holonomy, then a [theorem of de Rham implies that $M$ is a product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Reducible_holonomy_and_the_de_Rham_decomposition), and hence does not have homology generated by one element.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit more on this, i.e. why does reducible holonomy imply this. The link you gave is quite terse. @IanAgol

Comment: So to clarify, if $M$ is a simply-connected closed Riemannian manifold and has reducible holonomy then $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ has at least two generators? I am asking as I am not familiar with this result. @IanAgol

Comment: More precisely, Berger gave a complete classification of possible holonomy groups for the irreducible case; however, is such a complete classification know for the reducible case?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus: I guess the Wikipedia page doesn't mention that this is called the "de Rham decomposition theorem". In addition to the reference it gives to a proof of this theorem in Kobayashi-Nomizu, you can google the name of the theorem and find other expositions of it. Also, I guess this is implicit in my answer, but the fact that $H^*(M)$ is not 2-generated when $M=M_1\times M_2$ follows because $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^*(M_1;\mathbb{Q})\otimes H^*(M_2;\mathbb{Q})$ since the Kunneth theorem preserves cup products (and I suppose Poincaré duality is needed).

Comment: Thanks @IanAgol! One last question: Berger gave a complete classification of possible holonomy groups for the irreducible case; however, is such a complete classification know for the reducible case? Also, suppose $Hol(\nabla)$ is irreducible, then is it true that the homology is singly generated?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus: Coupling Berger's classification with de Rham's decomposition theorem, I suppose one does obtain a classification of reducible holonomy groups by requiring that each factor is one of the examples coming from Berger's list (actually, I'm not sure which on his list are realized by compact simply-connected manifolds). One can find metrics on product manifolds with irreducible holonomy, so the converse is false.

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus, I expect that a "generic" manifold in any reasonable sense will (a) have irreducible holonomy and (b) have homology that is not generated by a single element. So I expect the converse to be very false (but it's hard to quote precise results).

Comment: @IanAgol Can you think of a necessary condition on the above whose converse holds? Also, when you say we can get a classification of reducible holonomy groups by requiring that each factor is one of the examples coming from Berger's list (realized by compact simply-connected manifolds), do you simply mean $$Hol(M)=\bigotimes_{i_1=1}^{k_1}SO(n)\bigotimes_{i_2=1}^{k_2}(Sp\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)Sp(1))\bigotimes_{i_3=1}^{k_3}G_2\bigotimes_{i_4=1}^{k_4}Spin(7)$$ for $k_j=0,1$ and $j=1,...,4$?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus: Yes, that's right, where by your tensor product you mean a direct product of groups.